# Can't save result of "Extract Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)" inside the working feature dataset!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arctoolbox, file-geodatabase, feature-dataset

I have a file geodatabase in which I have a feature dataset. I have some feature classes inside the feature dataset. I wonder why when I attempt to save the result of [Extract Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm) inside my working feature dataset, the result is genereated inside the file Geodatabase but not under my feature dataset. No matter what I do I can't make it save the result inside my feature dataset. I can easily save the results of for instance [Extract Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm)  inside my working feature dataset. But "Extract Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)" seems to be different in that regard. Any idea why this is happening?

Edits:
I am using Arcmap 10.0 calling this tool from Arc toolbox. All the layers are in the same coordinate system. Here is a snapshot before I run the tool:

[image]

But as can be seen here the result is generated outside the feature dataset:
[image]

Comment: How are you calling this tool? Is your out point features like c:\path\file_gdb.gdb\dataset\points?

Comment: I am calling this tool from Arcmap, Arc toolbox. Yes, the putput I enter is something like "P:\Temp\Geodatabase.gdb\dataset\output"

Comment: Is the output coordinate system the same as the feature dataset? The output is a point feature class, is that right?

Comment: Yes, all the layers are in the same coordinate sytstem. That is correct.

Comment: I think you've found a bug in the tool. I have encountered this once before, I can't remember which tool or version, and got around it by using a two-step method in a model: first create the output, then copy the output into the desired location and then delete the temp output.

Comment: Hmmm...it seems so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a bug: NIM-070258 - The Extract Values to Points tool creates an output in the geodatabase when a feature dataset is specified as the destination. Found in 10.0 SP2 and [solved in 10.2](http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/102-IssuesAddressedList.pdf)!